# How do I find the memory location of items on the stack?

Tags: memory, stack, bit

In an interview, I was asked:

> You are given a stack with starting address of 0th. The value of the stack is 1000 and each location can store 8 bytes of data. What is the memory location of 42nd element ?

Comment: Not enough information to answer.

Comment: @tod :: many people have already given the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at some values and try to find a pattern.

```
0 -> 1000
1 -> 1008
2 -> 1016
```

It starts at 1000 and goes up by 8 each time, so

```
n -> 1000 + 8*n

42 -> 1000 + 8*42
42 -> 1336
```

Comment: thank you i got the answer now

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple.

- Element[0] = Memory[1000]
- sizeof(Element) = 8

Then:

```
Element[42] = Memory[1000 + 8*42]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Time S.

The statement "it grows up" is not necessarily true.
It can also grow down.

So you second example is more correct. N can be negative in that case.